# compiling on friendlyarm qtopia error

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, makefile

after trying to cross compile a program for a week i gave up and now im trying to compile it directly on the friendlyarm running qtopia 2.2.0, but when i run make i am getting some strange errors. Can some one shine some more light on the and maybe point me in the right direction on how to fix the problem?

the make output:

```
/sdcard/images/makef # make
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 2.2e+04 s in the future
gcc -c -o obj/main.o main.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/serial.o serial.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/fb.o fb.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/menu_main.o menu_main.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/timer.o timer.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/cmdin.o cmdin.c -I./
cmdin.c: In function 'processcmd':
cmdin.c:64: warning: format '%f' expects type 'float *', but argument 4 has type 'int *'
gcc -c -o obj/buzzer.o buzzer.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/statemachine.o statemachine.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/inout.o inout.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/network.o network.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/text_file_input.o text_file_input.c -I./
gcc -c -o obj/text_file_input_oven.o text_file_input_oven.c -I./
gcc -o main obj/main.o obj/serial.o obj/fb.o obj/menu_main.o obj/timer.o obj/cmdin.o obj/buzzer.o obj/statemachine.o obj/inout.o obj/network.o obj/text_file_input.o obj/text_file_input_oven.o -I./ -lgd -lrt

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/librt.so when searching for -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/librt.a when searching for -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/librt.so when searching for -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/librt.a when searching for -lrt
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../librt.a(timer_create.o): In function `timer_create':
timer_create.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../librt.a(timer_routines.o): In function `timer_helper_thread':
timer_routines.c:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../librt.a(timer_routines.o): In function `__start_helper_thread':
timer_routines.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
timer_routines.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
timer_routines.c:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
/sdcard/images/makef #
```

Also how can i get if this message:
**make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 2.2e+04 s in the future** 
i tried

```
touch *.*
```

but that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 2.2e+04 s in the
>   future

Your clocks on the system you are compiling on and the system that generated the files are out of sync. You should fix that (in another answer is mentioned a workaround using `touch`, but this is only a good idea if the "other computer" is running the wrong time - if your system you are compiling on is running the wrong time, then you should fix the time on the current system - ideally using `ntp` (network time protocol) to set your time on both systems from a network source at boot or similar - that way, you don't have to worry about them going out of phase either [a PC system clock will drift between 1 and 30 seconds in a month, depending on the actual hardware used].

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
>   /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/librt.so when searching for -lrt

These messages are harmless as long as the system is able to find some librt that "is compatible", and it seems like it does, since we get this.

> /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../librt.a(timer_routines.o)

The following indicates that libpthread is not being linked (in the right place)

> timer_create.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `pthread_once'

You need to use `-lpthread` on your linker line - after `-lrt`, since `librt` is what is using pthread functions. Note that libraries are sensitive to order (and sometimes you even need to give the same library twice, because there are cyclic dependencies)

Comment: oky after editing my makefile to **LIBS=-lgd -lrt -lpthread**  usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread

Comment: Probably should be /usr/lib?

Answer (score 1):

That message is usually an indication that some of your files have modification times later than the current system time. A possible solution is to "touch" every file in the source tree in order to update timestamps: go to the root of the subtree an do "find . -exec touch {} \; "

Then clean your project, delete all build files and retry compilation.

It seems that You have also forgotten to link libpthread. You should have posix libraries and link your project to libpthread.